# Time complexity O(n) for finding missing number?

Tags: java, time-complexity

I am trying to understand the time complexity.Someone [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113795/quickest-way-to-find-missing-number-in-an-array-of-numbers) mentioned that the time complexity is O(n) , please find the image below: Since it's `N(N+1)/2` , shouldn't it be O(n^2) as `N(N+1)` are in multiplication? Please correct me if I have misunderstood something.

[image]

Comment: If you're looking for clarification on an answer, you should post a comment on the answer with your question.

Comment: Since only one loop is present in the code from i=0 to n .. it is O(N)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be a comment on another question.

Comment: @JimLewis I think that this question has a lot of merit on its own. It gets at a subtlety of big-O notation that many people find confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code above *computes* n(n+1)/2, but that doesn't mean it *takes time* O(n<sup>2</sup>). For example, consider this code:

```
int x = n*n;
```

This code computes n<sup>2</sup>, but it runs in time O(1).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstood the answer: when the author says "the sum of natural numbers 1 through N is N*(N-1)/2", he provides a closed form expression for computing the sum *if all 100 numbers were present*. This value is computed in O(1).

Computing the sum of the 99 numbers from the list that is given to us takes O(N).

Answer (score 1):

Complexity is a measure of the resources required by an algorithm. In this case if the size `n` of the list doubles then the time required will also double. In other words the required time resource is proportional to `n`. This is expressed as O(n). It's irrelevant how long each step take; the only important thing is the amount of overall time taken in relation to the input.

Comment: So, if `N=200` then the complexity would be `O(n^2)` ? Similarly if `N=300` , would it be `O(n^3)` ?

Comment: @John perhaps I didn't explain it very well. The complexity is O(n) irrespective of n. It's really just saying that the time taken will be proportional to n.

Comment: Can't we use Binary search to find it in O(LogN) time as mentioned here http://java67.blogspot.com/2014/12/how-to-find-missing-number-in-sorted.html   considering number from 1 to 100 are sorted?